# Angular - Clean URLs - Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When loading the application I get this error but my server is working the way it should... What could be the problem?

I am serving the app with clean urls aka no hashtag.

Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I have come across multiple times and also seems others have since this is a recurring problem in Stackoverflow.

The solution is very simple.

```
 <base href="/">
```

However one caveat is that this handy little life saving tag needs to be right at the top of the  right under the  tag will solve it.

I wrote a post about it [here](http://powdertothepeople.tv/2016/11/20/Resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-MIME-type-text-html/)